# Connection timeout when trying to reach local web server from within local network

Tags: docker, server, timeout, vscode-server

I followed a YouTube tutorial on how to set up a VSCode server so that you can use it outside of your computer (my iPad). Like in the tutorial, I ran it in docker. The docker container is called **`gitpod/openvscode-server`** ([Here](https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server)).
I opened up the URL `localhost:3000` or `192.168.0.56:3000` on the PC where the server ran; of course it worked.
I then opened up the URL on my iPad but I got a **connection timeout**. Side Note: The ethernet cable of the PC is connected with the router that gives the WiFi for the iPad (It also worked in the past).

I thought it could have something to do with the vscode server. That's why I created a python web server using `python -m http.server 8080`. I opened the IP address on the PC and it worked as before.

On my iPad and on my smartphone however, it did not work: Again a connection timeout.

This is weird because, especially the python web server, should be working. It did so in the past without issues and I can't think of reasons why it does not work this time.

I also connected my smartphone with the ethernet but that did not even lead to a connection timeout. Just to a "*The server cannot be reached*".

Maybe you could help me.

**EDIT:**

I downloaded a terminal app on my smartphone and ran `python -m http.server 8080` there. Then I opened the URL with the ip address of my smartphone on the PC and it worked.
I do not why it is working one way but not the other.